# How do you sum a 2d array after brodcasting using MPI and C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, mpi

this is my first time ever using MPI (I am also quite new to C++ as well) and I am trying to do this challenge for a course and I am very confused. I think I have to be overthinking it, but basically I have to broadcast the given array to each node, have each thread (4) sum the array, and then reduce the result. What I believe I have left to do is just the summation section, but I cannot figure out how to do this in parallel after the MPI broadcast, as most examples online use send and receive and are also only one-dimensional. I need to add this under the comment ***// Need two lines of code here to sum the array (rows and columns)***, what is the proper way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

P.S. A lot of the code was provided from the instructor, but I did alter a few things here and there so feel free to correct anything else you see wrong or poorly-coded.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int procNum, procRank, m, n;
    int sumProc = 0, sumAll = 0;
    int** arr;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procRank);

    if (procRank == 0) {
        &m = 4;
        &n = 5;
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int sample_array[4][5] = {
    {50, 55, 62, 70, 85},
    {35, 42, 45, 47, 49},
    {32, 33, 36, 37, 38},
    {25, 30, 30, 35, 30}
    };

    arr = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[n];
    }

    if (procRank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sample_array[i][j];
                printf("%i ", arr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        MPI_Bcast(arr[i], m*n, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    {

    // Need two lines of code here to sum the array (rows and columns)


    sumProc += 1;
    MPI_Reduce(&sumProc, &sumAll, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (procRank == 0) {
        printf("sumAll = %i \n", sumAll);
    }

    delete *arr;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Looks like C code with the `new` operator.  A note about `new`: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) That said, because it is so heavily C-derived, there isn't much that can go wrong in this code that'll skip over the `delete` at the end without crashing the program first, so all you should have to worry about is using `delete` correctly. Everything you `new` you must `delete`. There are `m` +1 `new`s and only one `delete`.

Comment: First you should allocate your 2D array in contiguous memory (this is the best fit for MPI) and adopt a divide & conquer strategy: `MPI_Scatter()` your array (or `MPI_Scatterv()` if it cannot be evenly "split" between the ranks), compute the sum of the scattered (sub) array and then reduce the partial sums.